MatPlotLib Graph in a tkinter frame stays completly white
The graph supossed to be displayed in the canvas does not appear
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTk
import numpy as np

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Graphique Matplotlib dans Tkinter")
root.geometry("750x500")

t = np.arange(0, 3, 0.01)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))
canvas = FigureCanvasTk(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=0,y=0)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Cliquez-moi !")
button.pack()

root.mainloop()

I display a canvas in a window, a button, but the graph stays invisible, despite it being created when I write plt.show() to test.

Try adding canvas.draw().

It still stays white

Use FigureCanvasTkAgg(...) instead o f FigureCanvasTk(...).

I have that, but impossible to update the toolbar, it does not work on the new graphs created after clicking on the button
import random
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = None
toolbar = None

def cplot():
    global canvas, toolbar

    if canvas:
        plt.close()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack_forget()

    xCord = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(5)]
    yCord = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(5)]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.plot(xCord, yCord)

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    if not toolbar:
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    else:
        toolbar.update()

bouton = tk.Button(root, text="Changer", command=cplot)
bouton.pack()

cplot()

root.mainloop()


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You need to destroy and recreate the toolbar.  Note that you should update your question instead of posting updated code as answer.
